# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/iot/cbor/CborMap

Tags: java, intellij-idea, runtime

I'm following this tutorial:                                   https://gae-piaz.medium.com/green-pass-qr-code-signature-verification-java-f742079cc88 and this is its github repo https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/greenpass-verify.git
I used its same dependencies but i always get this error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/iot/cbor/CborMap at kapta.classes/kapta.Utils.GreenPassValidator.DecodeQRGreenPass.decode(DecodeQRGreenPass.java:43) at kapta.classes/kapta.Utils.GreenPassValidator.MainDecodeGreenPass.main(MainDecodeGreenPass.java:10) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.iot.cbor.CborMap at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ... 2 more`
This is my github repository that doesn't work. https://github.com/ManueleMustari/GreenPassManuele.git.
I don't understand why cauase they look the same. I added all the libraries to the dependencies correctly, in fact it  is only a run-time error. I tried to change the  scope from "compile" to "runtime"  and  to download the .jar too but they were useless. I tried to invalidate cache and restart, to reload maven but all  of them didn't work for me. Does somebody know what can i do to solve my problem? My INTELLIJ configuration are the default one, i didn't set them. The first project that i've linked worked with my intellij setup, but with the second project i've linked not. It seems it's my project problem. I've to use these function in a bigger project and i get always the same error, so i'm trying to solve it in a smaller one (the one i've linked) to understand what i'm missing. Hope somebody can help me, it has been two day without understand the problem.

Comment: Does it work if you build/run the project from the command line outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: I didn't try, i don't  know how to do